# git bash on windows vs. WSL

Tags: git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded git on my windows, and some other stuffs, including git bash, came along.

Although I didn't know why bash terminal has been included in the "git", 
it supported not only the functions for git, but other functions like mkdir, cp, mv, just like a real linux bash terminal.

Recently I came to know the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which makes bash terminal available in windows.

Is the git bash quite inferior to WSL in terms of functionality?

Does it contain some constraints that WSL doesn't have?

Comment: The exact question came up in google https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Bash-on-Ubuntu-and-Windows-and-Git-Bash

Comment: I also.use both on win10， my experience is that wsys provides a full set of tool chains that a linux system can offer(c++ compiler, apt-get for example), while git bash is a terminal simulator.

Comment: please feel free to add another answer (the two first seems to me uncomplete/ not understandable enough)..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/) is using the  [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) project (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32356595/6309)) and [**msys2**](https://www.msys2.org/).
See more in "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)".

That is vastly different from [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), which emulates an actual Linux distribution.

> Does it contain some constraints that WSL doesn't have?

The Git for Windows is based on a [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1780614/6309) compatibility layer, [which has limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27372958/6309): [POSIX support is deprecated since Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32355772/6309).

---

Note: WSL will soon be [replaced by WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012225/6309), which uses an entirely new architecture that uses a [real Linux kernel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/shipping-a-linux-kernel-with-windows/).

---

If your program depends on Git bash (and not WSL/WSL2 bash), make sure to put said Git for Windows first in `your` PATH, as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) described in "[USING “GIT BASH” FROM APPVEYOR](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/10/12/using-git-bash-from-appveyor/)", in an [AppVeyor CI environment](https://www.appveyor.com/).

```
# Make sure we get the bash that comes with git, not WSL bash
  - ps: $env:Path = "C:\Program Files\Git\bin;$env:Path"
```

Comment: Is it possible for git bash and git installed in WSL2 to coexist? I'd think it ought to be; yet, when I run `git status` within WSL2 in a repo I had worked on previously via git bash, it does a "refreshing index" and shows all files as modified. `git log` from WSL2 does show the correct log however.

Comment: @dqbydt What git version do you have in your WSL session?

Comment: WSL (Debian) git version: 2.20.1; git bash git version: 2.34.1.windows.1

Comment: @dqbydt Try first on Debian a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, then `git add --renormalize .`.

Comment: That shows as "Changes to be committed" all the files that it was previously showing as "not staged".

Comment: @dqbydt OK. What about (assuming you don't have local modification) a (stillon Debian WSL) `git reset --hard`, followed by a `git status`?

Comment: Yup, that seems to have done it! git bash also showed all files as modified, but after the `reset --hard`, both now appear to be in sync. Thank you!

Comment: @dqbydt Great! Well done.

Comment: confirming `git reset --hard` worked for me as well!

Answer (score 9):

WSL does not trigger file handlers when the file is changed in Windows tools - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

So, you cannot run a dev server in WSL, as code changes made a Windows editor will not be reflected in the dev server.

Comment: This was fixed in version 1903: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/